# Sql query using count(*) , groupby and fetching a column value simultaneously

Tags: sql

I am been developing application in java and not much insight into sql.
Meanwhile , I have got to fetch count and username in the same query. My query goes like this :

```
SELECT count(*),c_user_name
FROM tra_shipment_status
WHERE i_tra_shipment_status_id IN
  (SELECT MAX(i_tra_shipment_status_id)
  FROM tra_shipment_status
  WHERE i_status_code = '4072'
  AND c_reference    IN ('FILEIO0023','MIASTOFIL003')
  Group By C_Reference
  );
```

This throws me an exception "not a single-group group function"
I want the count and C_user_name of the top most row (latest one).
Can somebody please help.

Comment: Please add the tag for the DBMS you use

Answer (score 0):

If you use `count(*)` in the main query you also need a `group by` there:

```
SELECT count(*),c_user_name
FROM tra_shipment_status
WHERE i_tra_shipment_status_id IN
  (SELECT MAX(i_tra_shipment_status_id)
  FROM tra_shipment_status
  WHERE i_status_code = '4072'
  AND c_reference    IN ('FILEIO0023','MIASTOFIL003')
  Group By C_Reference
  )
Group by   c_user_name
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to include an aggregate function like `count`, `sum`, `max`,.. you should use `group by` with other unaggregated columns like `c_user_name` in your case. There is another thing; you say that you need the top most row but your sub query will return the top most row for each `C_Reference`, and to get the top most row regardless of `C_Reference` you should do something like the following:

```
SELECT count(*),c_user_name
FROM tra_shipment_status
WHERE i_tra_shipment_status_id IN
  (SELECT MAX(i_tra_shipment_status_id)
  FROM tra_shipment_status
  WHERE i_status_code = '4072'
  AND c_reference    IN ('FILEIO0023','MIASTOFIL003') 
  );  
 Group By c_user_name
```

Comment: Thank you so much Abdullah and Jens. It worked nicely.

Comment: can u please have a look at this question also?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089236/sql-optimization-with-indexes?noredirect=1#comment73260213_43089236